# Atribuir valor de uma variável JS para um elemento HTML?

Tags: php, javascript, html, funções

Seguinte, eu atribuí um valor à um botão, e passei para minha função através do **onClick**.
Só que agora, eu gostaria de pegar esse valor que está em `index` e colocar no input do meu modal... Como eu posso fazer isso?

Meu botão que chama a função:

```
<button data-var="<?= $cont ?>" onClick="funcaoModal(this)" class="dropdown-item" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#modal-atualizar">Atualizar></button>
```

Minha função:

```
function funcaoModal(element) {
        var index = $(element).data('var');
        
        
    }
```

Meu modal:

```
<div class="modal fade" id="modal-atualizar">
                    <div class="modal-dialog">
                        <div class="modal-content">
                            <div class="modal-header">
                                <h4 class="modal-title">Atualizar</h4>
                                <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close">
                                    <span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span>
                                </button>
                            </div>
                            <div class="modal-body">
                                <form action="solicitacao.php" method="POST">
                                    <div class="form-group">
                                        <label class="input-form col-md-6" for="ticket">Número do ticket:</label>
                                        <input class="input-form form-control col-md-12" type="text" id="ticket" name="ticket" value=""  readonly>
                                    </div>
```

Eu queria que o valor da variável fosse pro `value` do meu input, do modal.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Opa, você fez quase tudo certo, só precisa trocar o jeito que vc ta tentando acessar o atributo `data-var`, seria com o método `.attr()`, q daí tu passa o nome do atributo e seta/resgata o valor dele

```js
function funcao(element) {
  var dataVar = $(element).attr('data-var')
  $('input').val(dataVar)
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<button data-var="15" onclick="funcao(this)">Clique</button><br>
<input type="text">
```

Comment: Mt obrigado Andre, funcionou! Só fiquei com uma dúvida, esse data-var eu não conhecia, vi num outro tutorial. Eu consigo passar mais de um elemento nele? Se eu quisesse passar mais de um dado por exemplo, será que daria?

Comment: Que bom!! Olha, esse `data-var` foi um atributo personalizado que o tutorial usou, vc pode ter quantos quiser, e chama-los como quiser tbm, `id-produto` por exemplo, já sobre passar mais de um elemento, como se fosse um array, acho q nao, mas daí passando multiplos atributos talvez resolva pra vc